# How can I collapse my dataset to medians and 95% confidence intervals of the median in Stata?

Tags: stata

I wish to collapse my dataset and (A) obtain medians by group, and (B) obtain the 95% confidence intervals for those medians.

I can achieve (A) by using `collapse (p50) median = cost, by(group)`.

I can obtain the confidence intervals for the groups using `bysort group: centile cost, c(50)` but I ideally want to do this in a manner similar to `collapse` where I can create a collapsed dataset of means, lower limits (ll) and upper limits (ul) for each group (so I can export the dataset for graphing in Excel).

Data example:

```
input id group cost
1 0 20
2 0 40
3 0 50
4 0 40
5 0 30
6 1 20
7 1 10
8 1 10
9 1 60
10 1 30
end
```

Desired dataset (or something similar):

```
. list

     +-----------------------+
     | group   p50   ll   ul |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |     0    40   20   50 |
  2. |     1    20   10   60 |
     +-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
clear 
input id group cost
1 0 20
2 0 40
3 0 50
4 0 40
5 0 30
6 1 20
7 1 10
8 1 10
9 1 60
10 1 30
end

statsby median=r(c_1) ub=r(ub_1) lb=r(lb_1),  by(group) clear: centile cost 

list 

     +--------------------------+
     | group   median   ub   lb |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |     0       40   50   20 |
  2. |     1       20   60   10 |
     +--------------------------+
```

In addition to the usual `help` and manual entry, [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0045) includes a riff on essentially this problem of accumulating estimates and confidence intervals.